# How to regex strip p tags with styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this to strip p tags, but it does not get any with styling:

```
.replace('<p>','').replace('</p>','');
```

How can do this one?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove `p` tag just do:

```
$('someSelector').remove('p');
```

or if you want to unwrap `p` contents then do (which is what it seems like you are trying to do):

```
$('someSelector').find('p').contents().unwrap(); //keep the content of p there but remove the p wrapper.
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uRLP/)**

Comment: @RafaTost it did work. Inspect the element and see. and you are doing it wrong you should do it this way http://jsfiddle.net/7vkk4/

Comment: not in my code, the example works but not when applied in my situation. i have accepted the answer that worked. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression version of replace:

```
.replace(/<p.*>/g,'').replace('</p>', '');
```